# Why does ls -al suddenly take a very long time?

Tags: linux, filesystems

Suddenly `ls -al` takes an irritating long time, a normal `ls` is as quick as usual.

What can the problem be?

Comment: in addition to the extra `stat-ing` if you have symlinks in the directory, that may require the system to waken sleeping disks to confirm that the link is still healthy (ls -al color codes symlinks based on whether they point to a valid location).

Answer (score 1):

When `ls` is run it just shows you a list of files and nothing else. `ls -al` on the other hand shows much more information, and in order to do that it has to [stat(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stat) those files.

And if something is wonky with the file that operation can potentially take a long time.

My problem was that the group of some of the files no longer existed

```
-rw-------   1 nifle   10001    21499 Jan 25 14:31 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--   1 nifle   10001      304 Dec  6  2004 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--   1 nifle   10001      222 Dec 16 14:05 .bash_profile
-rw-r--r--   1 nifle   10001      124 Dec  6  2004 .bashrc
```

A simple `chown nifle:nifle .bash*` sorted the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it could be an alias thing, additional processing by shell or slow access to the storage device.

On mine, I've it as alias:

```
$ type ls
ls is aliased to `ls $LS_OPTIONS'
```

if that's the case, running as `\ls -al` could call it directly.

For the shell processing, you can check it by activating shell tracing, e.g.

```
$ set -x
$ ls
+ ls -G -h
README.txt index.php
++ update_terminal_cwd
++ local url_path=
++ local i ch hexch LC_CTYPE=C LC_ALL=
++ (( i = 0 ))
++ (( i < 26 ))
++ ch=/
++ [[ / =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=/
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 26 ))
++ ch=U
++ [[ U =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=U
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 26 ))
++ ch=s
... hundred of other lines
$ set +x
$ echo $PROMPT_COMMAND
update_terminal_cwd
```

Finally check your `ls` times:

```
$ time ls -la
...
real    0m0.025s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.004s
```

If your `sys` time is too high, check `load avg` in `top` command if anything slowing down your machine at the moment, alternatively please benchmark your hard drive, maybe you've a lot of I/O requests going on (check by: `iotop` or `vmstat`).

If this happens quiet often, always check with different shell or on tmpfs partition (`/tmp`) which should be much quicker.